# Upload a JPEG with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, image-uploading

I have a small problem with uploading a single image to my api. The api endpoint is finished it just expects an image.

I use the cordova camera plugin in my project to take a photo. It returns bas64.
I found a way to convert it to a jpg with the code below

```
 $scope.picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
            var blob = new Blob([$scope.picture], {type: 'image/png'});
            var picture = new File([blob], 'picture.jpg');
```

after i converted it (wich i assume works) i have the normal http directive from angular with the following code.

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: '/me/saveavatar',
     headers: {
         'Content-Type': undefined
         },
     data: {
         photo: picture
       }
     })
    .success(function (data) {
        console.log("success" + data);
     })
    .error(function (response) {
         console.log("error" + response);
    });
```

But i doesnt upload my file to the server. if it is a file in the first place. What am i missing?

the complete function look like:

```
$scope.takePicture = function(){
        var options = {
            //these are option that are passed to the function so we can grab the picture and zise it the way we want.
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 250,
            targetHeight: 500,
            allowEdit : true,
            quality:100

        };
       //the plugin is calling upon the camera the plugin is called cordovaCamera
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(data) {
         //succes handeling
           $scope.picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + data;
            var blob = new Blob([$scope.picture], {type: 'image/png'});
            var picture = new File([blob], 'picture.jpg');
            //uploading the picture
                console.log(picture);
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/me/saveavatar',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    },
                    data: {
                        photo: picture
                    }
                })
                    .success(function (response) {
                        console.log("success" + response);
                    })
                    .error(function (response) {
                        console.log("error" + response);
                    });
        },
        // Error handeling
        function(){
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Camera afgesloten?',
                template: 'U kunt altijd nog een foto maken!'
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: getting any errors?

Comment: i have to test on a real device i got nothing. no triggers on the .success and .error

Comment: If your testing on an actual phone why not use alert instead of console.log to try and see the errors!

Comment: i used the alert i got null back its the trigger on the .error thanks for the advice ill keep it in mind but i still have no idea on where to go from here